# How to change the content of page depending on the value in request param by a click on link or url?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

So basically i have home page and i want to change the content of my page if click on a link or through my url depending upon a value in request param and i want to manage this by angular js.

here is my html file code:

```
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Trading - CorDapp</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/bootstrap.min.css" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/style.css" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css"  crossorigin="anonymous">
    <script src="assets/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="assets/js/bootstrap.min.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="assets/js/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="assets/js/ui-bootstrap-tpls.min.js"></script>
    <script src="assets/js/ng-loading-overlay.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/angular-module.js"></script>
</head>
<body ng-app="tradingAppModule" ng-controller="TradingAppController as demoApp">
<nav class="navbar navbar-default">
    <a class= "navbar-brand">
    <img style="max-width:200px;max-height:100px;margin-bottom: 80px;" src="iglogo.png" alt="not found">
    </a>
</nav>
```

this is my anchor through which i want this change:

```
<div class="tradeId"><h4><a ng-click="demoApp.openTransactionDetailsModal(trade.linearId.id)" href="">Trade ID - {{trade.linearId.id}}</a></h4></div>
```

this is my angular js file content:

```
const app = angular.module('tradingAppModule', ['ui.bootstrap','ngLoadingOverlay']);



// Fix for unhandled rejections bug.

app.config(['$qProvider', function ($qProvider) {

    $qProvider.errorOnUnhandledRejections(false);

}]);



app.controller('TradingAppController', function($http, $location, $uibModal) {

    const demoApp = this;



    // We identify the node.

    const apiBaseURL = "/api/trading/";

  demoApp.openTransactionDetailsModal = (tradeId) => {

       demoApp.currentTradeId=tradeId;

       const modalInstance1 = $uibModal.open({

            templateUrl: 'TransactionDetailsModal.html',

            controller: 'TransactionDetailsTradeCtrl',

            controllerAs: 'modalInstance',

            resolve: {

                demoApp: () => demoApp,

                apiBaseURL: () => apiBaseURL,

                peers: () => peers

            }

        });

        modalInstance1.result.then(() => {}, () => {});

    };
```

Controller:

```
app.controller('TransactionDetailsTradeCtrl', function ($http, $location, $uibModalInstance, $uibModal, demoApp, apiBaseURL, peers) {

    const modalInstance = this;

    modalInstance.peers = peers;

    modalInstance.form = {};

    modalInstance.formError = false;

    $http.get(apiBaseURL + "getTrade?linearID="+demoApp.currentTradeId).then(

        (response) => modalInstance.transactionDetails = response.data

        );

    // Close create Trade modal dialogue.

    modalInstance.cancel = () => $uibModalInstance.dismiss();



});
```

Currently it's just displaying a json string without ui but i want a  complete ui.Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You have to study [angularjs routing](https://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial/step_09).

Comment: But it doesn't make use of request params